# how to connected to the wcf named pipe from other language(C,Qt...)

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have a wcf namedpipe host ,it works well by .net client wcf proxy.
Now, need to support communication with qt client.

I cannot get the real name of the wcf namedpipe,it`s random guid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name implies, `NetNamedPipeBinding` is intended only for use by .Net clients (similar to `NetTCP` binding). .Net is more than capable of communicating over named pipes using the basic IO library outside of WCF, which is the recommended choice if you will be mixing in non-.Net clients.

Comment: Inter-process communication across language,which is the best way,namedpipe or socket?

Comment: I'm no expert but:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178138(v=sql.80).aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235958/ipc-performance-named-pipe-vs-socket