# IPC performance: Anonymous Pipe vs Socket

Tags: performance, sockets, tcp, pipe, benchmarking

This question is similar to [IPC performance: Named Pipe vs Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235958/ipc-performance-named-pipe-vs-socket) but focusses on **anonymous** instead of **named** pipes: How is the performance difference between an anonymous pipe and a TCP connection on different operating systems and with different transfer sizes?

Comment: On Linux, I don't think there's any difference between named vs. anonymous pipes.  It's just a mechanism to establish a pipe between two processes other than creating in a common parent that forks/execs them.  (Other than setup overhead of course, having to open() via a pathname instead of a pipe() system call.)

Answer (score 5):

I tried to benchmark it using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) with the code attached at the end of this post. When the program starts, it initializes BenchmarkDotNet which in turn invokes the `GlobalSetup()` methods once and the two benchmarked methods (`Pipe()` and `Tcp()`) many times.

In `GlobalSetup()`, two child processes are started. One for pipe communication and one for tcp communication. Once the child processes are ready, they wait for a trigger signal and the number of values `N` to be transferred (provided via `stdin`) and then start sending data.

When the benchmarked methods (`Pipe()` and `Tcp()`) are invoked, they send the trigger signal and the number of values `N` and wait for the incoming data.

It has shown that it is important to set `TcpClient.NoDelay = true` to disable the Nagle-Algorithm that first collects small messages until a certain threshold or a certain timeout is reached. Interestingly this affects only the Linux tests with `N = 10000`. With `NoDelay = false` (default), the average time for this test jumps from `~40 µs` to `~40 ms`.

Here are the results:

**Legends**

- N         : N = number of int32 values to be transmitted
- Mean      : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
- Error     : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
- StdDev    : Standard deviation of all measurements
- Median    : Value separating the higher half of all measurements (50th percentile)
- Ratio     : Mean of the ratio distribution ([Current]/[Baseline])
- RatioSD   : Standard deviation of the ratio distribution ([Current]/[Baseline])
- 1 us      : 1 Microsecond (0.000001 sec)

**Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 20.04)**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=ubuntu 20.04
AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4334, 4 CPU, 4 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.102
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.2 (5.0.220.61120), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.2 (5.0.220.61120), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Pipe** | **1** | **27.33 μs** | **1.660 μs** | **4.895 μs** | **30.75 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 1 | 31.42 μs | 0.620 μs | 0.713 μs | 31.24 μs | 1.39 | 0.21 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **100** | **26.72 μs** | **1.990 μs** | **5.867 μs** | **26.63 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 100 | 38.95 μs | 2.146 μs | 6.327 μs | 43.34 μs | 1.53 | 0.43 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **10000** | **42.45 μs** | **2.804 μs** | **8.268 μs** | **47.09 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 10000 | 46.97 μs | 3.057 μs | 9.013 μs | 53.93 μs | 1.16 | 0.34 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **1000000** | **1,621.87 μs** | **116.924 μs** | **344.752 μs** | **1,893.49 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 1000000 | 1,707.25 μs | 8.066 μs | 7.545 μs | 1,707.24 μs | 0.94 | 0.13 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **10000000** | **21,013.86 μs** | **166.250 μs** | **129.797 μs** | **21,007.89 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 10000000 | 20,548.03 μs | 407.779 μs | 814.379 μs | 20,713.44 μs | 0.96 | 0.03 |

**Notebook (Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 + WSL2):**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=ubuntu 20.04
Intel Core i7-8650U CPU 1.90GHz (Kaby Lake R), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.301
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.7 (5.0.721.25508), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.7 (5.0.721.25508), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Pipe** | **1** | **44.66 μs** | **0.882 μs** | **1.051 μs** | **44.45 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 1 | 54.42 μs | 0.411 μs | 0.364 μs | 54.34 μs | 1.21 | 0.03 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **100** | **45.07 μs** | **0.895 μs** | **1.496 μs** | **44.63 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 100 | 55.27 μs | 0.735 μs | 0.614 μs | 55.17 μs | 1.21 | 0.05 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **10000** | **52.30 μs** | **1.018 μs** | **1.131 μs** | **52.32 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 10000 | 55.47 μs | 0.590 μs | 0.523 μs | 55.32 μs | 1.06 | 0.03 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **1000000** | **4,034.01 μs** | **77.978 μs** | **65.115 μs** | **4,035.58 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 1000000 | 1,398.62 μs | 24.230 μs | 21.479 μs | 1,395.20 μs | 0.35 | 0.01 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **10000000** | **69,767.35 μs** | **4,993.492 μs** | **14,723.423 μs** | **64,169.46 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 10000000 | 24,660.43 μs | 1,746.809 μs | 4,955.406 μs | 23,947.15 μs | 0.38 | 0.14 |

**Notebook (Windows 10):**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1083 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-8650U CPU 1.90GHz (Kaby Lake R), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.203
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.6 (5.0.621.22011), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.6 (5.0.621.22011), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Pipe** | **1** | **22.60 μs** | **0.441 μs** | **1.013 μs** | **22.21 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 1 | 27.42 μs | 0.535 μs | 1.019 μs | 27.51 μs | 1.21 | 0.08 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **100** | **21.93 μs** | **0.146 μs** | **0.122 μs** | **21.94 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 100 | 26.06 μs | 0.506 μs | 0.474 μs | 25.99 μs | 1.19 | 0.02 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **10000** | **29.59 μs** | **0.126 μs** | **0.099 μs** | **29.58 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 10000 | 33.25 μs | 0.655 μs | 0.919 μs | 33.01 μs | 1.14 | 0.04 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **1000000** | **1,675.35 μs** | **32.862 μs** | **43.870 μs** | **1,685.37 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 1000000 | 2,553.07 μs | 58.100 μs | 167.631 μs | 2,505.34 μs | 1.63 | 0.10 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Pipe** | **10000000** | **23,421.61 μs** | **141.337 μs** | **132.207 μs** | **23,380.19 μs** | **1.00** | **0.00** |
| Tcp | 10000000 | 28,182.91 μs | 375.644 μs | 313.679 μs | 28,114.22 μs | 1.20 | 0.01 |

Benchmark code:

*Benchmark.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.13.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*Program.cs*

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Benchmark
{
    public class Program
    {
        public const int MIN_LENGTH = 1;
        public const int MAX_LENGTH = 10_000_000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!args.Any())
            {
                var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<PipeVsTcp>();
            }
            else
            {
                var data = MemoryMarshal
                     .AsBytes<int>(
                         Enumerable
                             .Range(0, MAX_LENGTH)
                             .ToArray())
                     .ToArray();

                using var readStream = Console.OpenStandardInput();

                if (args[0] == "pipe")
                {
                    using var pipeStream = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
                    RunChildProcess(readStream, pipeStream, data);
                }

                else if (args[0] == "tcp")
                {
                    var tcpClient = new TcpClient()
                    {
                        NoDelay = true
                    };

                    tcpClient.Connect("localhost", 55555);
                    var tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    RunChildProcess(readStream, tcpStream, data);
                }

                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid argument (args[0]).");
                }
            }
        }

        static void RunChildProcess(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream, byte[] data)
        {
            // wait for start signal
            Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[4];

            while (true)
            {
                var length = readStream.Read(buffer);

                if (length == 0)
                    throw new Exception($"The host process terminated early.");

                var N = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);

                // write
                writeStream.Write(data, 0, N * sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*PipeVsTcp.cs*

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Benchmark
{
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class PipeVsTcp
    {
        private Process _pipeProcess;
        private Process _tcpProcess;
        private TcpClient _tcpClient;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            // assembly path
            // under Linux the Location property is an empty
            // string (why?), therefore I have it replaced 
            // with an hard-coded string
            var assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

            // run pipe process
            var pipePsi = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet")
            {
                Arguments = $"{assemblyPath} pipe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            _pipeProcess = new Process() { StartInfo = pipePsi };
            _pipeProcess.Start();

            // run tcp process
            var tcpPsi = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet")
            {
                Arguments = $"{assemblyPath} tcp",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            _tcpProcess = new Process() { StartInfo = tcpPsi };
            _tcpProcess.Start();

            var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 55555);
            tcpListener.Start();

            _tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            _tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
        }

        [GlobalCleanup]
        public void GlobalCleanup()
        {
            _pipeProcess?.Kill();
            _tcpProcess?.Kill();
        }

        [Params(Program.MIN_LENGTH, 100, 10_000, 1_000_000, Program.MAX_LENGTH)]
        public int N;

        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public Memory<byte> Pipe()
        {
            var pipeReadStream = _pipeProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            var pipeWriteStream = _pipeProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream;
            using var owner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(N * sizeof(int));

            return ReadFromStream(pipeReadStream, pipeWriteStream, owner.Memory);
        }

        [Benchmark()]
        public Memory<byte> Tcp()
        {
            var tcpReadStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
            var pipeWriteStream = _tcpProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream;
            using var owner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(N * sizeof(int));

            return ReadFromStream(tcpReadStream, pipeWriteStream, owner.Memory);
        }

        private Memory<byte> ReadFromStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream, Memory<byte> buffer)
        {
            // trigger
            var Nbuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(N);
            writeStream.Write(Nbuffer);
            writeStream.Flush();

            // receive data
            var remaining = N * sizeof(int);
            var offset = 0;

            while (remaining > 0)
            {
                var span = buffer.Slice(offset, remaining).Span;
                var readBytes = readStream.Read(span);

                if (readBytes == 0)
                    throw new Exception("The child process terminated early.");

                remaining -= readBytes;
                offset += readBytes;
            }

            var intBuffer = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(buffer.Span);

            // validate first 3 values
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(N, 3); i++)
            {
                if (intBuffer[i] != i)
                    throw new Exception($"Invalid data received. Data is {intBuffer[i]}, index = {i}.");
            }

            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```